# Lines in background image

Tags: html, css

So I have a background image on my site, but if you look closely enough, you can see a small line running through the image above the first div box (named `.transbox2`) and below the second div box (named `.transbox`).  Why are those lines there and can I remove them?

I took a screenshot of what the image looks like. You can find it here:

[image]

You'll see what I mean with the background image.

Finally, here's the background image by itself.  Notice that no lines are present above or below the top and bottom of the div boxes:

[image]

Here's my CSS:

```
#minimal_table_for_Master_Evan {
    font-family: "Calibri", "Times New Roman", Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 55%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: left;
}

#minimal_table_for_Master_Evan td {
    color: #000;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

html, body {
    background-image:url("ADPBackground.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
p, h2, h4, li {
    font-family: "Calibri", "Times New Roman", Serif;
}

li {
    list-style-position:inside;

}

.transbox {
    width: 50%;
    margin:30px 50px;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255, 0.3);
    filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    border-radius:25px;
    padding: 2em;
}

.transbox2 {
    width: 50%;
    margin:30px 50px;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255, 0.6);
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    border-radius:25px;
    padding: 1em 2em;
}

.transbox p {
    margin:30px 40px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000000;
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<center>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet-test.css"/>

<title></title>

</head>

<body>

<div class="transbox2">
<img src="logo" width="134" height="60">
</div>

<div class="transbox">

<h2>Header</h2>

<p>
    Nice paragraph
</p>

<h4>Header</h4>

<ol>
    <li>Blank text</li>
    <li>Blank text</li>
    <li>Blank text</li>
</ol>

<form method="post" action="mailto:name@email.com">

<table id="minimal_table_for_Master_Evan">
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>

<p></p>

<input type="submit" value="Save" id="save">
</form>
</div>

</body>

</center>
</html>
```

Comment: Linky to your website would be awesome to demonstrate the problem visually. Alternatively put it in jsfiddle

Comment: ...and how exactly would we see this?

Comment: Hard to tell without being able to see what you're talking about.

Comment: I can't add images because I don't have enough reputation points (I need 10).  If two of you can upvote my post then I can post the image.  IF you do not want to give me reputation points, I totally understand.

Comment: Just host the images on http://postimage.org and then use http://jsfiddle.net to recreate the issue.

Comment: This was closed as supposedly lacking sufficient information.  However, there are screenshots and complete code.  Voting to re-open.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that is happening is because of the  background-repeat: repeat;
To fix this, change is to no-repeat: true; and set the html height to 100%

Comment: 1: If I set the height to 100%, then there is an annoying scroll bar on the side and the page will scroll up and down. 2: how do I set the "no-repeat: true"?  Do you mean "background-repeat: no-repeat"?  I tried both and neither worked.

Comment: Using no-repeat will nto work unless you have the html height to 100%, but if there is a scroll bar, then you may need to change the height of some divs, unless you can stop the scrollbar any other way, sorry if this is no help.

Comment: Sorry, this didn't help. :(